# Input file for polar_scan_matcher package

Tags: ros, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use a package called ["polar_scan_matcher"](http://polar_scan_matcher). I would like to know how do I supply/input my laser scan data as it is in ".txt" file (it should be in ".bag" file, I guess) and it contains not only raw laser scan data, but also other data that are not needed for this package (Or else, it will be an error).

My implementation plan is to write my own node that will subscribe /pose2D topic from the package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12037/input-file-for-polar_scan_matcher-package/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll need to write some code that builds `LaserScan` messages from your .txt file. I suggest the [rosbag API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag) as the place to start; it gives you tools for writing messages into bagfiles.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0